# Save in mongodb and pass created object to a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm beginner at programing and I don't know how can I do something with the mongoose save result.
In my post endpoint I would like to not save and directly return but instead of it I would like to do something with the result of save method like take the _id value of the new object created and pass to a function.

Here's what my post endpoint is doing and I would like to after saving not return but instead call a function passing the checkout object created:

```
router.post('/', async function(req, res) {
    const { checkinId, eventId, email } = req.body;
    let CheckoutTest = {
        checkinId: checkinId,
        eventId: eventId, 
        email: email,
    } 
    const newCheckout = new Checkout(CheckoutTest);
    await newCheckout.save((err, checkout) => {
        if(err) {
           return res.status(400)
           .send(err);
        }else {
           return res.status(200)
           .json({message: "Checkout successfully added!", checkout});
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An elegant way to do this would be to add a try...catch block

```
router.post('/', async function(req, res) {
        const { checkinId, eventId, email } = req.body;
        let CheckoutTest = {
        checkinId: checkinId,
        eventId: eventId, 
        email: email,
    } 
    const newCheckout = new Checkout(CheckoutTest);

    try {
        const newCheckoutObject = await newCheckout.save()
        // Call the function that you wanted to after the save. 
        // You can pass in the "_id" of the object as shown here
        const newData = await functionToBeCalled(newCheckoutObject._id)
        return res.status(200).json({message: "Checkout successfully added!", newData});
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).send(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to return this: return res.status(200).json({message: "Checkout successfully added!", checkout});
I would like to return the return of the function I want to call